# Error while adding xmlns:xsi attribute namespace to root element

Tags: php, dom, xsd

I have a xml called sample.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<note>
         <to>Tove</to>
          <from>Jani</from>
          <heading>Reminder</heading>
          <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

and sample.xsd to validate sample.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
targetNamespace="http://www.w3schools.com"
xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com"
elementFormDefault="qualified">

         <xs:element name="note">
                  <xs:complexType>
                           <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element name="to" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="from" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="heading" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="body" type="xs:string"/>
                           </xs:sequence>
                  </xs:complexType>
         </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

I'm trying to validate sample.xml through my php code and since there are no namespaces in sample.xml I'm adding the namespace from the php code.

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

$file = 'sample.xml';
$schema = 'sample.xsd';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load($file);

$doc->createAttributeNS('http://www.w3schools.com', 'xmlns');
$doc->createAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance', 'xmlns:xsi');
$doc->createAttributeNS('http://www.w3schools.com sample.xsd', 'xsi:schemaLocation');

print $doc->saveXML();


if ($doc->schemaValidate($schema)) {
         print "$file is valid.\n";
} else {
         print "$file is invalid.\n";
}
?>
```

and when I run the code I get the following error

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'DOMException' with message 'Namespace
>   Error' in /var/www/xsd/test_sample.php:20 Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/xsd/test_sample.php(20):
>   DOMDocument->createAttributeNS('http://www.w3.o...', 'xmlns:xsi') #1
>   {main} thrown in /var/www/xsd/test_sample.php on line 20

if I comment out the line `$doc->createAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance', 'xmlns:xsi');` the code runs fine but then I'm not able to validate the xml as it says `sample.xml is invalid`

Can some one help me with this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing I would fix would be to also use [appendChild](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.appendchild.php) on your [document element](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php#domdocument.props.documentelement). Without that, the attribute is created but not appended to your tree.

For validation, please take a look at [this link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-validxphp/).

Comment: Are you sure I have to use appendChild, because I've tried to comment `$doc->createAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance', 'xmlns:xsi');` in my code and then checked the xml, it still contains the rest of the two namespaces. I'll have a look at the link which you have provided :)

Comment: Yes, I am sure; creating a node doesn't append it to the tree - all DOM APIs are like that :)...

Comment: Wierd case with me :) I don't know why but `createAttributeNS` adds the namesapce without calling `appendChild`. Any ways your link has helped me a lot. Thanks

Comment: You're right, it is weird; I went by the documentation posted [here](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createattributens.php)... hmmm...

Comment: Yes, the main PHP API documentation is _not correct_ for this method. But, the [first note](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createattributens.php#98210) on the relevant PHP docs page does explain it correctly: "With createAttributeNS(), the new namespace is declared in the document as soon as the attribute is created - the attribute does not actually have to be inserted..."

Answer (score 1):

Point of clarification on Searock confusion on why it is necessary to use appendChild when using createAttribute but not when using createAttributeNS.

The internal functionality of the two functions are designed differently even though they are named similarly:

createAttributeNS() automatically appends the NameSpace Attribute to the document.

createAttribute() must be appended with appendChild().